# Is Keras fit_generator the best thing to use when handling data that does not fit in RAM?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, hdf5

I am working to build a classifier that can classify [Knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_(mathematics)). Currently I have a dataset that contains 100,000 images of "unknots", 100,000 "plus trefoil", and 100,000 "minus trefoil".

I have been trying to get a classifier working on this large data set for the last 4ish days. The list of problems I had so far were:

1) Data set does not fit in CPU main memory: fixed this by making a number of `EArrays` with PyTables and Hdf5 and appending them on disk. So now I have one 1.2Gb file which is the dataset.

2) Even a very simple neural network in Keras was hitting 100% GPU (nvidia k80) memory usage after the **model compiled**... hadn't even fit the model yet. I read this was due to Keras backend automatically allocating near 100% of available resources upon compile: I fixed this as well.

3) Once errors 1 and 2 were fixed, I was still getting strange accuracy from Keras `fit_generator()`.

Questions:

1) Is the method I have described of merging small numpy arrays into one large `EArray` using PyTables a good way to make a very large (300,000 images 128x128, total size = 1.2Gb) dataset?

2) Should fit generator be used over `train_on_batch` in Keras? Will they return significantly different final loss/accuracy scores?

3) What is wrong with my generator method if I want to train the neural network on batches of 50 images from the hdf5 file, and after each training epoch, delete the images the network just trained on out of main memory?

```
import tables
hdf5_path = "300K_Knot_data.hdf5"
extendable_hdf5_file = tables.open_file(hdf5_path, mode='r')

def imageLoader(files, batch_size):

    L = len(files.root.train_data)

    #this line is just to make the generator infinite, keras needs that    
    while True:

        batch_start = 0
        batch_end = batch_size

        while batch_start < L:
            limit = min(batch_end, L)
            X = files.root.train_data[batch_start:limit]
            X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0],128,128,3))
            X = X/255
            Y = files.root.train_label[batch_start:limit]

            yield (X,Y) #a tuple with two numpy arrays with batch_size samples     

            batch_start += batch_size   
            batch_end += batch_size

img_rows, img_cols = 128,128
###################################
# TensorFlow wizardry
config = tf.ConfigProto()

# Don't pre-allocate memory; allocate as-needed
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

# Only allow a total of half the GPU memory to be allocated
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5

# Create a session with the above options specified.
K.tensorflow_backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
###################################

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(96, (3,3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax', name='preds'))


#lr was originally 0.01

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.01, epsilon=None, decay=0.0),metrics= 
['accuracy'])

# fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:

model.fit_generator(imageLoader(extendable_hdf5_file, 50),
                steps_per_epoch=240000 / 50, epochs=50)
```

Here is the output of fitting the model:

[image: Output of fitting the model.]

Sorry if this is not the correct place for the post.
My research adviser is out of town, and I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to fix this issue and I just need some input, because I cannot find an adequate solution on the internet, or cannot seem to wrap my head around what I do find well enough to implement it in a nice manner.  I am not a new programmer, but am relatively inexperienced  in python.

Comment: In the image you have posted it seems the training has stopped(!!!), right?

Comment: Yes. I stopped it because the fit generator keeps starting at 100% accuracy at the beginning of each epoch, will stay at 100% until about step 3000 then start plummeting until it gets near 33%. I haven’t let it train for long, but it’s done this a couple times and I thought it was incorrect. You can see the loss goes from over 10 to basically zero in the second epoch. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the way you have defined your generator is fine. Nothing seems to be wrong with it. Although, currently using [Sequence class](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) is the recommended way especially because it is much safer when doing multi-processing. However, using generator is fine and it is still heavily used.

As for the weird accuracy numbers, you mentioned that it is 100% for 3000 steps and then it drops to 33%. I have the following recommendations to diagnose this:

1) Decrease the learning rate to for example `3e-3` or `1e-3` or `1-e4`. I recommend to use an adaptive optimizer like `Adagrad` or `RMSprop` or `Adam`. I recommend `RMSprop` with the default parameters; don't change any parameters first, instead experiment with it and make changes according to the feedback you get (if the loss decreases very slowly then increase the learning rate a bit; if it increases or is stable then decrease the learning rate, though these are not definite rules. You must experiment and take into account the validation loss as well). Using an adaptive optimizer reduce the need of using a callback like `ReduceLearningRateOnPlateu` (at least not until you have solid reasons to use it).

2) If it is possible for you, split your whole data into train/validation/test sets (or at least train/validation). The ratios of 60/20/20 or 70/15/15 are the most commonly used ones. But make sure that the classes in each of those three sets are equally represented (i.e. you have more or less the same number of "unknots", "plus trefoil", "minus trefoil" in each set). Note that their distribution should be more or less the same as well. For example you should not handpick the easy ones for the validation and test set. Usually selecting after shuffling the whole data (i.e. to make sure they are not in any particular order) would work. Creating a validation set helps you to make sure that the progress you see during training process is real and the model is not over-fitting on the training data.

You need to define a new generator for validation and pass the validation data (i.e. load the file which consists of validation data) the same way you have done with training data. Then set the `validation_data` and `validation_steps` arguments of `fit_generator` method with appropriate values.

3) Using batch normalization before or after the activation is [still debatable](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1802#issuecomment-187966878). Though, [some people claim](https://github.com/ducha-aiki/caffenet-benchmark/blob/master/batchnorm.md#batch-normalization) that it works better if you put it after the activation or exactly right before the next layer. You can experiment with this as well.

4) If you are not using your GPU for anything else, then use its full capacity (i.e. don't limit its RAM usage). And use a batch size which is a power of two (i.e. 64, 128, 256, etc.) since it helps with GPU memory allocation and may speed it up. 128 or 256 seems good choices considering the number of samples you have.

5) If training for one epoch takes a lot of time then consider using [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) and [`EarlyStopping`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) callbacks.

Comment: It takes about 10 minutes for the first epoch and is still doing the same thing. I could upload a youtube video of it training if that would help, or post the actual jupyter notebook! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MattWard ignore this solution. The indentations in your python code distracted me. Have you tried different learning rate? For example `1e-3` or `1e-4`? And just set the learning rate. Don't change decay for example. It is strange that for the first 3000 steps the accuracy is 100% and then drops. I have never seen such a thing before. One more thing: remove that BatchNormalization layer. It should not be there I think. At least not before activation function.

Comment: I changed the learning rate to 0.001 and now performance for at least 5 epochs is way more stable and training accuracy is remaining around 99%.  I was thinking of adding in the keras callback "ReduceLearningRateOnPlateu", what do you think of this? The reason I hadn't been messing with hyperparameters is because previously I had been using a Bayesian optimization algorithm I wrote, but my advisor didn't want me using that for now.  Also, when training in batches like this, how would you handle evaluating the validation/test set? Thanks very much.

Comment: @MattWard I am writing your response in an answer since comments have character limits. It may take a few minutes.

Comment: Ok sounds good thank you. FYI the hdf5 file has fields root.test_data and root.test_label but I hand selected which data is test data.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: My validation set is 60,000 samples, which will not return a whole number when divided by a power of two. For instance, if I chose a batch size of 128, that is 468.75. So the number of steps should be 468.75...in order to cover the entire validation data set once per epoch. Is it ok to round this number up to 469? Or round down to 468? Thanks.

Comment: @MattWard It is not important if a few samples are trained over two times in a epoch. But make sure that all samples are covered. However, you can modify your generator to produce the last batch consists of 96 samples: `30000 - 128x468 = 96` or `30000 % 128 = 96`; so the last batch is smaller and it is completely OK. Actually, read the description of `generator` argument of `fit_generator` method in [the docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator): "... the last batch of the epoch is commonly smaller than the others, if the size of the dataset is not divisible by the batch size."

Comment: @MattWard Or you can modify your generator such that the last batch consists of the last 96 samples plus the first 32 (128 - 96) samples from the beginning. In both cases, with batch size of 128 and 60000 samples then the number of steps is 469. (BTW, In the previous comment I mistakenly said 30000 samples. It  is 60000 as you said. Other numbers are correct.)

Comment: @today Thanks, this is one of the best answers I've ever seen. One question: How could I make sure that all samples are covered? Shuffle the whole dataset first and then pick them in an order? I don't think it's a efficient way though.

Comment: @WWH98932 I am sorry, but I can't understand your question. What do you mean by "make sure that all samples are covered"? Where? When spliting the data into train/test splits? And why do you think shuffling is not possible or efficient? How is your data stored, and how many samples are there? As a side point, shuffling is something which is also done internally when you call `fit` method at the beginning of each epoch (see [the explanation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method) for `shuffle` argument).

Comment: @WWH98932 I got what you meant. I answered this question 2 years ago, so I had forgotten the context. Now re-read it. Note that splitting the data into train/test split is a one-time task. Now if you are loading the data from disk chunk-by-chunk (with whatever method) and they are sorted in any particular order, then to get a random split two options come to my mind: either change the data loading process to access random parts of file-data for generating each batch, or instead write a custom script which creates separate train/test files from your data and then you can load them separately.

Comment: @today To make sure I have covered all samples in during fitting process. I mean, if I'm using fit_generator and do not want to feed the data in an order, I have to randomly shuffle them first, but it brings the risk that some of the data might not be selected in the whole fitting process.